# Spark executor logs on YARN

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-manager

I'm launching a distributed Spark application in YARN client mode, on a Cloudera cluster. After some time I see some errors on Cloudera Manager. Some executors get disconnected and this happens systematically. I would like to debug the issue but the internal exception is not reported by YARN.

```
Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_1417503665765_0193_01_000003 and exit code: 1
ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I see the stacktrace of the exception? It seems that YARN reports only that the application exited abnormally. Is there a way to see spark executor log in YARN configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check NodeManager's `yarn.nodemanager.log-dir` property. It's the log location of when Spark executor container is running.

Note that when the application finishes NodeManager may remove the files (Log Aggregation). Check this document for detail. http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This didn't let me find the full stack trace of the exception but now I know the cause of the problem (OperationNotSupportedException, only the description is present on the log you suggested). If you know a way to find the full stack trace, let me know.

Comment: You may want to catch the exception durng your function passed to transformes.

Comment: I am trying to catch it and dump the trace to a local file in the /tmp folder. I was hoping there was a cleaner solution..

Comment: Just print stack trace to stdout and check the file in yarn.nodemanager.log-dir, after confirming which NameNode take your executors (by checking ApplicationMaster's log).

Comment: Finding logs used to be so easy, YARN totally breaks everything, now it's a massive faff.