# Spark Executor Custom Logs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, mapr

I've been supplying custom log4j properties to spark-submit in below manner:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --queue qqqq \
  --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/absolute path/to properties file/driver-log4j.properties" \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/absolute path/to properties file/executor-log4j.properties" \
  --class com.abc.spark.def.MyClass myApp.jar arg1 arg2
```

Spark logs show that these driver and executor log4j properties are being read correctly. I am able to see the application logs written to driver logs but nothing in executor logs.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539254/custom-log-using-spark), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454080/how-to-log-using-log4j-to-local-file-system-inside-a-spark-application-that-runs),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843186/custom-log4j-appender-in-spark-executor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336265/spark-executor-logs-on-yarn). Has anyone run into this issue earlier? If it helps, this code runs on MapR platform.

Comment: May be you need to add `--files` option to put log4j file to executor

Comment: @cue - thank you for your input. I tried it, didn't work for me.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm facing similar issue